# Braintree gives me unexpectedError

Tags: node.js, braintree

I signed up into braintreepayment and added the merchantID, publickey and the private key and can't get the clientToken at all instead it gives me error and when i searched for that error i found out it's unknown error in the braintree documentation, and no one has same problem that being fixed

it's my first time to use braintree

this is the code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const User = require('../models/user');
const braintree = require('braintree');

const gateway = braintree.connect({
    environment: braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
    merchantId: process.env.BRAINTREE_MERCHANT_ID,
    publicKey: process.env.BRAINTREE_PUBLIC_KEY,
    privateKey: process.env.BRAINTREE_PRIVATE_KEY
});

module.exports = {
    generateToken(req, res){
        gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function(err, response){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).send(err);
            } else {
                return res.send(response.clientToken);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

this is the route file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const {requireSignin, isAuth} = require('../controllers/auth');
const {userById} = require('../controllers/user');
const {generateToken} = require('../controllers/braintree');


router.get('/braintree/getToken/:userId', requireSignin, isAuth, generateToken);

router.param('userId', userById);

module.exports = router;
```

it gives me an error like that

{
    "name": "unexpectedError",
    "type": "unexpectedError"
}

Comment: did you find the issue?

Comment: yes I just changed the DNS into google 8888 and 8844